# Не запускается Python бот

Tags: python, бот

проблема либо запускается бот, но не запускается программа, лобо запускается программа, но не запускается бот

Код:

```
#импорт библиотек
from tkinter import *
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

#содание главного окна
root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x500')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

#создание бота
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
client = discord.Client()

#проверка готовности бота
@bot.listen('on_ready')
async def ready():
    print('Бот успешно запущен!')

#фукнкции бота
@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    ctx.send(f'Hello, {ctx.author.mention}')


#графические элементы программы
hello = Button(text='Поздороваться с пользователем', command=hi)
hello.place(x='10', y='20')



#запуск бота и цикла программы
root.mainloop()
bot.run('OTQxOTczODI0MTU5NzQ0MDIw.YgdvfA.2-JQ3WgUO01J3ikuyzDfx6IeyCQ')
```

Хочу подключить к боту граф.интерфэйс, подскажите как решить данную проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Сделайте бота и интерфейс отдельно.

Так будет лучше и проще.

Без этого не работает решение.**

```
bot.py - Ваш бот.
ui.py - Ваш интерфейс.
```

**А вот решение.**

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from threading import Thread
from bot import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x500')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

hello = Button(text='Поздороваться с пользователем', command=hi)
hello.place(x='10', y='20')

run_bot_thread = Thread(target=lambda: bot.run('OTQxOTczODI0MTU5NzQ0MDIw.YgdvfA.2-JQ3WgUO01J3ikuyzDfx6IeyCQ'))
run_bot_thread.start()

root.mainloop()
```

**Вы запускаете программу, то-есть, пока будет запущена программа, бот не запуститься.**
**Если вы сделаете наоборот, сначала бота, потом программу, то программа не запуститься пока бот будет работать.**
**Поэтому нужно запустить бота в другом потоке и потом программу.**